# Questions marked as duplicate refer to the duplicate, but the other way around does not occur

Tags: feature-request, questions, duplicate-questions

Sometimes when a question is marked as a duplicate it has already 'developed' into an interesting Q&A link.

An example is [Could dark matter be wrong?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27413/could-dark-matter-be-wrong) on the Astronomy website which is marked as duplicate of [Are there any alternative explanations for the gravitational force we attribute to dark matter?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/are-there-any-alternative-explanations-for-the-gravitational-force-we-attribute). (I am using this as an example because it triggered me to write this question/request, but there are many other examples).

Now, the 'problem' that I see, is that the question that is marked as duplicate links to that particular duplicate question, *but* the other way around does not occur.

This is problematic in such cases where the marked question is actually having useful and interesting (possibly better than the original) answers.

My suggestion is that we should also link back from the question that is the duplicate question, to the question that has been marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

This already happens; the question marked as a duplicate is on the right in the 'Linked' section:

[image]

Note that there are other ways for a question to end up here; most notably if it's linked to in a comment or answer.

Comment: I never really noticed that part of the website. Can we say that it is working well/sufficiently (ie do people use those links)? The position of the notification at the top, in the case of a closed question, is much more salient. If we want people to find (the best) answers to questions should we not hide them in some menu on the right side?

Comment: If the questions are identical, moderators can *merge* them and both answers will appear under the same question. Ideally, a question should be closed as a duplicate before answers are being written. In some cases, you could ask the author(s) to move their answer to the other question.

Comment: I know about the merging. But (1) sometimes the answers have a specific way of wording that makes them less suitable to be automatically placed under the other question. (2) the voting doesn't make sense (which is more generally a problem that newer answers have less history in comparison to old answers and this makes different questions differently judged and creates little incentive to post new answers to old, less active, questions since they tend to become seen as less important. ) (3) When we merge then we loose one of the questions which would have been helpful for the search-ability.